# Unable to understand Euler totient function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory

I came through the following implementation of Euler-totient function

```
    int fi(int n) {          
    int result = n;          
    for(int i=2;i*i <= n;i++) {            
        if (n % i == 0) result -= result / i;            
        while (n % i == 0) n /= i;          
    }          
     if (n > 1) result -= result / n;          
     return result;        
   }
```

I am unable to understand the purpose of following result statements
 
`result -= result / i;`
`result -= result / n;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
 result -= result / i;
```

equals:

```
 result -= (result / i);
```

which equals:

```
 quotient = result / i;
 result -= quotient;
```

which equals:

```
 quotient = result / i;
 result = result - quotient;
```

The second statement is very similar.